# Yet another YUV viewer source code?

Tags: open-source, yuv, viewer

There used to be source code for Yay (Yet another YUV viewer) that had support 4:2:2, 4:2:0 and 4:0:0 (Y-only) files. The one on Github is the much older version with only 4:2:0 support.

Does anyone still have the source code for the newer release? The following links don't work anymore:
http://mattzz.dyndns.org/twiki/pub/Projects/YetAnotherYUVviewer/yay-20100327-1.tgz
http://freshmeat.net/redir/yay/60653/url_tgz/yay-20060421.tgz

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found it on Github. It is at:

https://github.com/ramaxlo/yay

for those who may be looking for the source code themselves